# Can i sort an integer array, order by with difference items?

Tags: .net, arrays, sorting

I have a integer array

```
Dim intArray() as integer = {1, 1, 5, 9, 9, 10, 15, 15, 23, 25}
```

I want order with difference values this array

1-1, 9-5, 10-9, 15-15, 25-23  = {0,4,1,0,2}

Order again with ascent:  {0,0,1,2,4}

And i want this result

```
intArray = {1, 1, 15, 15, 9, 10, 23, 25, 5, 9}
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you try Array.Sort()?

Comment: No, because it is not easy way for this.. Perhaps linq is better..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do it with LINQ:

```
Dim result = intArray _
            .Select(Function(x, i) New With {.Value = x, .Index = i}) _
            .GroupBy(Function(x) x.Index \ 2) _
            .Select(Function(x) x.Select(Function(y) y.Value).ToList()) _
            .OrderBy(Function(x) x(1) - x(0)) _
            .SelectMany(Function(x) x) _
            .ToArray()
```

This code first selects the value and index of each element (because we need the index to be able to group each two elements together), and then it groups every two elements together and puts them into their own list (its like we have a list of size-two lists). It then orders these lists by the difference between the second and first values. It then recreates a single list for the list of lists.